# How can I access the web console of CodeReady Containers, installed on CentOS Docker container, from Host machine?

Tags: centos, networking, docker, container, haproxy

I have this scenario:

- a HOST machine running Debian that runs docker containers.
- a CentOS docker container that have **CodeReady Containers (CRC)** installed on itself. CRC working on the container, via command line, without problems.

I want access, from the Host machine, to CRC web console that works on `https://console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing` (on a specific IP in the `hosts` file).

I found this [RedHat guide for accessing CRC remotely](https://www.openshift.com/blog/accessing-codeready-containers-on-a-remote-server/). But how can I apply it to docker containers logic?
And above all, do I really need it?

---

I had to make the following **changes to `haproxy.conf`**:

```
global
log 127.0.0.1 local0
debug

defaults
log global
mode http
timeout connect 5000
timeout check 5000
timeout client 30000
timeout server 30000

frontend apps
bind CONTAINER_IP:80
bind CONTAINER_IP:443
option tcplog
mode tcp
default_backend apps

backend apps
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
option ssl-hello-chk
server webserver1 CRC_IP:6443 check

frontend api
bind CONTAINER_IP:6443
option tcplog
mode tcp
default_backend api

backend api
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
option ssl-hello-chk
server webserver1 CRC_IP:6443 check
```

and **enabling forwarding** for the container:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
$ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

I can successfully call the url `https://console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing` from the Host machine!!! but I get this error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Anyway the Network part is solved. Now I don't know why I get this error!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at browser side. Select Advanced and view certificate, then accept the risk. You will be directed to the Web Console login page for you to provide username and password

Comment: Of the all things that could be, certainly it isn't that! I suppose. The problem is there via CLI too, without the browser!